# onListItemClick gives error?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I hava a listview with each row containing a textview and checkbox. Now what I want is that when I click the textview the checkbox must be checked accordingly. I tried using this code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected item no."
             +(position+1)+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

if (v != null) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.Checkbox);
    checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
    }
}
```

Here's my whole code:

```
public class MyActivity3 extends Activity {
private TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my3);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcat);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);

    String[] listArray = new String[] { "All", "Friends & Family", "Sports", "Outside", "At School", "Fitness", "Photography", "Food", "Beach", "Money" };
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("status", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Boolean[] checkedStatus = new Boolean[listArray.length];
    for ( int index = 0; index < checkedStatus.length; index++)
        checkedStatus[index] = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Integer.toString(index), false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, listArray, checkedStatus);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected item no."
            +(position+1)+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (v != null) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chk);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation8, R.anim.animation7);
    }
}
```

Now  in the line    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); , onListItemClick is red. Any idea why?

Cristiano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to work with itemClickListener.

We need to set OnItemclickListener with list view object. in which we override onItemClick method.

**update**

```
public class MyActivity3 extends Activity {
private TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_my3);
Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcat);
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(typeface);

String[] listArray = new String[] { "All", "Friends & Family", "Sports", "Outside", "At School", "Fitness", "Photography", "Food", "Beach", "Money" };
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("status", MODE_PRIVATE);

Boolean[] checkedStatus = new Boolean[listArray.length];
for ( int index = 0; index < checkedStatus.length; index++)
    checkedStatus[index] = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Integer.toString(index), false);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, listArray, checkedStatus);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // do here whatever you want :-)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected item no."
        +(position+1)+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

        if (view != null) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chk);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
      }
        }
    });
   }
```

Comment: Instead of my onListItemClick I have now?

Comment: write it in oncreate method not outside of oncreate

Comment: Alright, it's not red anymore. Do I need to put this code inside the method for my question? : CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox)
if(cb.isChecked())
 cb.setChecked(false);
else 
 cb.setChecked(true);

Comment: check my updated answer.. you can implement your logic in onItemclickListener like whether checkbox id checked or not

Comment: v. is red, does it matter if I delete the v? ** EDIT It doesn't work.. the app doesn't crash but when I tap the row the checkbox doesn't get marked

Comment: use view.findviewById instead of v.findviewById

Answer (score 3):

Because Activity doesn't have an `onListItemClick()`, so when you are calling `super.onListItemClick()` , it throws a compile Time Error because there is no such function in it's parent class. if you want use `onListItemClick()` you should extends your class from `ListActivity`.

Comment: you can use : listView.setonItemClickListener(this) , or you can extends your class from ListActivity.

Comment: @CristianoWilson : please read this Tutorial :  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html